# Complex Analysis residues

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be a circle centred at the origin with radius $R$.

Show that $$ \int_D e^{t(z+z^{-1})} \cdot z^{-2}\, dz = \sum _{m=0} ^\infty B_m t ^{2m+1}$$

My ideas here are

- Find singularities within my domain $D$:

> $z= 0$ is obviously one, but other may arise from $e^{(z^2 -1)/z}$
>   
>   How would I calculate the residue here?
>   What should be my next few steps.

Comment: You will not have any other singularities from you exponential expression. The reason is Because you have only $z$ in the denominator. This means that your only singularity is $z = 0$. You can have `zeros` in your `exp`-function but you don't have to worry about them.

Answer (score 0):

Because the only singularity is $z=0$, you should calculate residue here.You can do it this way:

$e^{tz}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n z^n}{n!}$

$e^{t\frac{1}{z}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n z^{-n}}{n!}$, so:

$e^{tz}*e^{t\frac{1}{z}}*z^{-2}=(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n z^n}{n!})(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^n z^{-n}}{n!})*z^{-2}$

Now you should find $\frac{1}{z}$ coefficient.

Comment: So essentially your taking the C_ -1 coefficient of the laurentian expansion. But is there a slicker way of finding the residue?

Comment: Yes, there are some methods, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_%28complex_analysis%29. But in  this case singularity is essential, so I think it's the simpliest way.